# stopping a loop when i is over 8 or when input is -1

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to break a loop with the i in a loop or when the user types in -1, but every time I run the code it always seems to pass that statement

```
  for (i = 0; i < userValues.length; ++i) {
     userValues[i] = scnr.nextInt();
     if(userValues[i] == -1){
        break;
        }
     if(i > 8){
        break;
        }   
  }
```

Comment: `i > 8` means the the loop has run more than 9 times. Would that be where your problem is?

Comment: I don't a necessary problem with your code.  Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `userValues`?

Comment: why don't you add the `i` condition to the `for` loop (if that is really needed, that is, if `userValues` has more than 9 elements): `for (i = 0; i < userValues.length && i <= 8; i++)`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: adding another condition to the loop seem to have made it work now